# Como paginar gridview en C#.net visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paginacion

Tengo un aplicativo el cual me muestra datos en una grilla al clickar un boton. Segun ciertos parámetros que le mande antes de presionar el boton la grilla me puede traer muchos datos por lo que requiero paginarlo. Fui a propiedades del grid y marque el Allow Paging en true y PageSize en 10 para que me bote 10 registros por pagina. Luego después de chekar y buscar información sobre ello, en la clase de mi formulario en el evento puse algo como esto:

```
                  private void Migrid_PageIndexChanged(object sender, Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.PageEventArgs e)
    {
                  Migrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    }
```

Pero me bota error de que al parecer no reconoce el page index: 'Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.UltraWebGrid' does not contain a definition for 'PageIndex'

Nota: Como se pudo apreciar uso Infragistics para el diseño y el control del gridview es un UltraWebGrid.

Answer (score -1):

private void Migrid_PageIndexChanged(object sender, Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.PageEventArgs e)
{
Migrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

```
   // coloca la siguiente intruccion
   Migrid.DataBind();
```

// debria funcionar

```
}
```

Comment: Sería una excelente oportunidad para que explicaras esto de las grillas y la página. Una buena respuesta será útil a muchos, te dará puntos y aumentará tu reputación. Lo que publicas, lamentablemente, sólo puede que le sirva al OP. Una pena. Edita tu pregunta y explica la solución.